# How to give one file uploaded value to input (file) tag on second page?

Tags: php, forms, web, server

i use a form in which i get a file from user and submit it with button and take the values to another page with help of post(method). On the other page i have some business to do with that file beside that i have another form on that page. Now i want when submit that form (as it execute the php self script) so i want beside the new values i get that same file again. i try different technique like putting the tmp name in  a variable but that doesnot work and even i create another file button in the form of that page but i am unable to give it a value. In short i need idea how to get the file on submittion of that second page form which is send from first page ?
For simplicty let me show you an example so you understand my problem,

```
//the first page form
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadExcelData">
      <label for="csv_file">Upload CSV File</label>
      <input type="file" id="csv_file" name="csv_file" />
      <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" 
      value="upload" />
</form>
//on submit it goes to another page which have this php code and html form

<?php 
      $file = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];

      if (isset($_POST['save'])) { // the second form on submit 

             echo $file; //this show nothing 
      }

?>

 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
  value="Upload" />

  </form>
```

keeping above code in mind i hope somebody will understand the problem and suggest me something but i just summarize my code too much the second form also have many combobox etc and also i tryed to have a second file tag in second form but the problem is i cant even assign the file value to it so that it is selected automatically.
i want to get the file as output which have that shitty excel data!!

Comment: use this `print_r($_FILES)` and check this result

Comment: of course i did that ! its empty

Comment: try like `if(isset($_POST['upload'])){ print_r($_FILES);}`

Comment: @devpro i am not a kid ye! on resubmittion the $_files turn into empty because in second form there is no file to be added to that array ye ! so i need that the file data store in some variable to use it later or to create a input tag in second form and do something to automatically select the file there again. but i dont know how to do it

Comment: good luck Afridi :) but one last suggestion, check error log also.